# ViewPager and FragmentTabHost display content twice

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabhost, android-support-library

I have tabs that contains `Fragment` and i want to provide the swipe gesture to move right and left. I'm using it inside of `Fragment` and inside of activity. I use `ViewPager` inside of `FragmentTabHost` both from `support.v4` package (need to work on >=API 10). The problem is that the pager starts showing the content from the top of layout and tabhost is showing the tabs first and then the content. Of course i want the second behavior. So what i see is the content twice, one with tabs and one without. Here is my layout xml file. Notice that i have also some other views above the tabhost `(@+id/relative_header)` so action bar tabs don't fit in this case. I've already try to move pager into `realtabcontent`  or above it with no luck.

```
 <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relative_header" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"> 
        </TabWidget>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

I'm not sure but I assume that one of them is incompatible with the other, but i don't know which compination should use to provide swipe gesture between fragments tabs. Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, i'm writing this answer for anyone will have the same question in future. I misunderstood the role of each layout. `ViewPager` and `TabHost` doing more or less the same thing. To enable the swipe gesture i should have used ViewPager. To add tabs to this, i used the library [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) , also on Feb. 14 2014 seems that android team released a native layout for this: [PagerSlidingTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/project.html) . The tricky point was that tabhost has content and tab in the same layout but it cannot provide the swipe gesture.